# Best Way to Design database for AutoComplete Functionality

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, database-design

Best Way to Design database for AutoComplete Functionality.
I have following usecase(using technologies JAVA,SPRING,HIBERNATE,Mysql):

I have Professional Details Which is Associated with Skills(Many to Many Relationship).

```
public class ProfessionalDetailsDTO {

    private Integer professionalId;
    //many to many
    private List<SkillsDTO> profileSkills;

    setter and getter ...

}


public class SkillsDTO  {
    private String skillName;
    private Integer skillRating;
    private Integer skillId;

    setter and getter
}
```

Now From UI When I type Type Skills I should get the Valid Skills Suggestion (like JAVA,Hibernate).people might Save Dummy Skills or abrupt value
 (e.g XYZ )in Skill Table ,So I don't Want to Show This as suggestion in autoComplete.

**I Can Think of Following Approaches Right Now:-**

**Approach 1 :** Having Four Tables as mentioned below

**1.ProfessionalDetails**

```
column:professionalId
```

**2.Skills**
    column:SkillId,skillName,skillRating

**3.Professional_Skills**
    column:skillId,professionalId

**4. PreDefinedSkill**
    column:id,SkillName

Is it BestPractice to have one more table for preDefined Skills Which will be used for AutoSuggestion and The SkillName Fetched from the
 predefined Table will be stored in the skills table?

Cons:SkillName Will be Duplicates in the Skills Tables.

**Approach 2 :** In this Approach SkillRating is Moved to professional_Skills Table and Skillname is unique in skillTable
 Here I have to Map SkillDTO to Tables.I have to use annotaion Such as @secondaryTable.

**1.ProfessionalDetails**
    column:professionalId

**2.Skills**
    column:SkillId,skillName

**3.Professional_Skills** 
    column:skillId,professionalId,,skillRating

**Approach 3** .Same as Approach 2 but instead of using hibernate annotation use query's to insert into professional_Skills table.

**Please Suggest me Some Best Industry Practices To Implement the Above usecase**
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That's broad, you might want to rephrase

Comment: :) Ya I have Listed Three Approaches Which comes to my mind.Just Want get Some Highlight on the Above approaches Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

The Best Solution to Implement the Above use case(i.e Many to many with Additional Columns) is described in the Below Link:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany
Posting this as this might Help others.